# How do I get the answers to this javascript problem?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

```js
function multiplyAll(arr) {
  var product = 1;

  for ( var i = 0; i< arr.lenght; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j < arr[i].lenght; j++) {
      product *= arr[i][j];
    }
  }

  return product;
}

var product = multiplyAll([[1,2], [3,4],[5,6,7]]);
console.log(product);
```

I am expected to get `5000+` as the answer

Comment: There is a typo here: `arr[i].lenght`. It should be `arr[i].length`.

Comment: If you press F12 to open your development tools you can look at the console log to see if errors with your code are appearing.

Answer (score 2):

Both your `for` loops have a typo: The property is called `length`, not `lenght`. In JavaScript, accessing a nonexistant property evaluates to `undefined`. `0 < undefined` evaluates to `false` if `x` is a number, so the outer and inner `for` loop won't run and you'll get `1`. Fix the typos and it works as expected (I'd also recommend to use `let` and `const` over `var`):

```js
function multiplyAll(arr) {
  let product = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      product *= arr[i][j];
    }
  }

  return product;
}

const product = multiplyAll([[1,2], [3,4],[5,6,7]]);
console.log(product);
```

Such mistakes could be avoided by using `for`-`of` loops:

```js
function multiplyAll(arr) {
  let product = 1;
  for (const subarr of arr)
    for (const num of subarr)
      product *= num;
  return product;
}
const product = multiplyAll([[1,2], [3,4],[5,6,7]]);
console.log(product);
```

Or even better, using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const multiplyAll = (arr) => arr.reduce((prod, subarr) => prod * subarr.reduce((prod, num) => prod * num, 1), 1);
const product = multiplyAll([[1,2], [3,4],[5,6,7]]);
console.log(product);
```

And with [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```js
const multiplyAll = (arr) => arr.flat().reduce((prod, num) => prod * num, 1);
const product = multiplyAll([[1,2], [3,4],[5,6,7]]);
console.log(product);
```

Comment: Luatic is absolute right. Very good explanation. Was about to post the same piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another good option with flatMap()

[MDN flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Basically it can make one dimensional array from nested array of arrays

In your case

```js
function oneDimensionArr(arr) {
  const product = arr.flatMap(subArray => subArray)
  return product;
}

const arr = oneDimensionArr([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]);
console.log(arr);
```

Add reduce to calculate

```js
function multiplyAll(arr) {
  const product = arr.flatMap(subArray => subArray).reduce((acc, curr) => acc * curr, 1);
  return product;
}

const product = multiplyAll([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]);
console.log(product);
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been indicated, changing `.lenght` to `.length` should resolve your bug as in the snippet.

```js
function multiplyAll(arr) {
  var product = 1;

  for ( var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
      product *= arr[i][j];
    }
  }

  return product;
}

var product = multiplyAll([[1,2], [3,4],[5,6,7]]);
console.log(product);
```

However, you could also use `Array#reduce` and recursion as follows:

```js
function multiplyAll(arr, n) {
  if( Array.isArray(arr[0]) ) {
    return multiplyAll(arr.slice(1), multiplyAll(arr[0],n))
  } else {
    return arr.reduce((p,c) => p*c, n)
  }
}

var product = multiplyAll([[1,2], [3,4],[5,6,7]], 1);
console.log(product);
```

You could also use `Array#reduce` with `Array#flatMap` as follows:

```js
function multiplyAll(arr) {
  return arr.flatMap(sub => sub).reduce((prod,cur) => prod*cur, 1);
}

var product = multiplyAll([[1,2], [3,4],[5,6,7]]);
console.log(product);
```